# How is data stored in memory beyond 0s and 1s?

Tags: memory, data, storage

I am working as software engineer. As far as I know the data being stored in memory (either HARD Disk or RAM) is  0s and 1s.

I am sure beyond 0s and 1s there are different ways data is being stored in memory devices based on memory device types.

Please share your ideas about it.

Where can I study about how data is stored in memory devices?

Comment: You appear to have two questions. 1) In what logical form is data stored in memory at the lowest level. 2) What technologies are used.- 1) Most storage is binary = 1/0 or hi/low as this suits most technologies used and gives high density. Some earlier systems (mostly Russian I think) used base 3 as more computationally efficient. Some early systems appeared to use eg base 10 / BCD but usually used base 2 underneath.  2) Technologies - Others will answer :-) ...

Comment: The same way we write down big numbers when only ten digits are available.

Answer (score 3):

Digital data is generally stored as 1s and 0s at some level.  That is only the view of one level in a large layered hierarchy.  Below that you get into charges, phase change of material, mechanical dimples, voltages in active circuits, little regions of magnetic domains, and lots more ways people have come up with over the years to store bits (the 1s and 0s).

Above the bit layer there is a hierarchy eventually surfaced to applications as a file system by the operating system.  There are several layers above the bits and below the file system, but these vary depending on the exact storage device and the file system.

In general, large storage devices like disks, will present their memory as "sectors" or "blocks" that are the minimum amount that can be written or erased at once.  In flash drives there is a layer that does "wear leveling" that swaps around physical blocks to implement the logical blocks presented upwards.  Flash blocks have a limited write and erase lifetimes, and this layer seeks to wear them out as evenly as possible.  Magnetic disks don't have this issue, but do sometimes have a "bad spot" layer that avoids physically defective blocks from the logical blocks presented upwards.  Blocks usually contain CRC checksums implemented by the hardware.

The file system usually deals with the logical blocks directly.  It uses some as index to know what it stored in others.  Some file systems log operations to aid in recovery.  There are lots of strategies for knowing which blocks are used to store the content of which files, which blocks are empty, etc.  File systems often add their own checksums to logical blocks or files and other structures.

Eventually the file system presents a collection of "files" to the operating system.  The OS will usually define a few files for its own purposes, then present something a little different to applications.  How much different depends on the OS and whether it is intended to deal with multiple possibly hostile processes and other concerns.

Eventually the application sees arbitrarily sized collections of data, called files, it can read and write without having to worry about sectors, blocks, or how individual bits are physically stored.  Modern file systems tend to present files as named entities in a tree structure.

Answer (score 1):

As a side note: a research field is quantum computing, where people is trying to store information in the form of quantic particles (that can have whatever state until they are read) also called [Qubit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qubit).

But AFAIK there still isn't any device implementing this technology.

Answer (score 0):

Data on hard drives is stored as 1s and 0s which are physically represented by magnetized particles and non-magnetized particles. I suggest you start reading this wiki article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_storage_device and go on from there.

Answer (score 0):

Most devices store and process information using two-state devices because, in most cases, the amount of circuitry required for a device is proportional to something between the number of self-stabilizing states, and the square of the number of self-stabilizing states.  If a ternary device with three stable states took only 1.5 times the circuitry of a binary device with two stable states, then twelve ternary devices could hold slightly more information than nineteen binary devices, while using only 36/38 times as much circuitry.  In practice, though, the three-state devices would need a bit more than 1.5 times as much circuitry, so two-state devices end up being more efficient.

The only areas where binary isn't used almost exclusively are those where information is held or transmitted in devices that are not continuously self-stabilizing, and where the size and expense of the material carrying the information is large relative to the amount required to stabilize it; the two largest such areas are flash memories and communications cables.  It's possible to store more than two states in a flash memory cell, or send more than two voltages down a communications cable, without increasing the cost of the memory cell or the cable.  Using more than two states will substantially increase the cost and complexity of the interface circuitry, but if the cost of the memory cells or cables exceeds by an order of magnitude the cost of the data-retrieval circuitry, cost savings that could be achieved by cutting the number of cells or cables in half would dominate even a four-fold cost increases in the cost of interface circuitry.